# отбразить таблицу из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД MySQL, в ней создана таблица, содержимое этой таблицы вывести на веб страницу, но выдается ошибка

> *bool(false)
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in F:\home\localhost\www\result1.php on line 21*

вот листинг:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("3ax") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "`id`SELECT * FROM `rab` WHERE 1";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

var_dump($rs);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) - это 20 строка, на которую указывается в ошибке
{
$row)
  echo $row['id'] . "<br />";

}
```

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0):

ошибка тута

```
$strSQL = "`id`SELECT * FROM `rab` WHERE 1";
```

исправьте его на

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `rab` WHERE 1";
```